# Error when using 'include' documents in pages that are in a folder

Tags: php, file, include, directory

When load up a page that is in a folder, i get errors from trying to load the included docs on the page;

```
 <?php
include ('Resources/core/init.php');
include ('Resources/includes/header.php');
include ('Resources/includes/head.php');
include ('Resources/includes/footer.php');
 ?>
```

They work fine when i use it on my index page which isn't in a container folder in the website. for example the root to my index page is: `websitename/index.php` but my other pages are in folders like: `websitename/pages/aboutus/contactus.php` . These aren't the exact names for the website pages it's just an example. Does anyone know what i can do about this?

Comment: please paste some codes to help us help you.

Comment: Use absolute path http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: try `include ('/Resources/includes/footer.php');` and as -Robert- saidalso you should use absolute path for that.

Comment: I've never heard of an "absolute" path before can you give me an example please?

Comment: using your example it still doesn't work

Comment: @HarrisonWood sure first you should save site root (in ie $root) with variables you have in $_SERVER. and if file is in root in `Resources/includes/footer.php` do this `include $root.'/'.'Resources/includes/footer.php';`

Comment: @HarrisonWood please let us know how are you talking to by adding `@name` in begining of your comment.

Comment: @HarrisonWood: are you sure the files even exist? Try replacing the `include` calls with `echo file_exists('Resources/core/init.php') ? 'Yes' : 'No';`, if the output is No, you're trying to include a non-existent file, also try `echo realpath('/Resources/core/init.php');`, and see what that returns

Answer (score 1):

As most comments/answers stated: an absolute path is the best way to go. Perhaps take your inspiration from frameworks, such as ZenFW. The index.php file's location is a given, in that file, define a constant:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));//depending on where the index.php is in your case.
```

From there on, use the constant:

```
include (APPLICATION_PATH.'/Resources/core/init.php');
```

If needs must, add a `realpath` call to the mix:

```
include(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../Resources/core/ini.php');
```

[the docs](http://www.php.net/realpath) for `realpath` here.

Comment: +1 yes a perfect way for doing that as frameworks do that too

Answer (score 0):

Always use absolute path. At least

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Resources/core/init.php';
```

Comment: It didn't load any of the content within the document using your code

Comment: use absolute paths in your HTML **as well**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep using relative paths you need to use the double dot to jump back a level, for example if its 2 folders deep you would use

```
<?php
    include ('../../Resources/core/init.php');
    include ('../../Resources/includes/header.php');
    include ('../../Resources/includes/head.php');
    include ('../../Resources/includes/footer.php');
?>
```

but of course you should listen to others and create an absolute path constant and prepend it to the path if you're using multiple file locations on an app that loads the same files relative, its going to be a pain